# How to reduce the numbers of states in a BFS algorithm?

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

i have a BFS algorithm in Python. Im creating the tree while going trough it. Here is the code of my implementation:

```
def bfs(initial_state,target):
   
    visited =[]
    queue = [initial_state]
    
    find = False

    while not find: 
     
        s = queue.pop(0)
        
       

        #Target 
        for r in s.robots:
            if  r.x == 5 and r.y ==10:
                    print("FIND")
                    return visited
        #If the state dosent have child -> Creating his childs
        if not s.childs:
            
            s.create_child()
        
       
        for child in s.childs:
            if child not in visited: 
                visited.append(child)
                queue.append(child)
```

Here i want to try a solution in 3 moves, when i print the length of visited list it print 20k states. That is way too much because each parent has 16 childs , so a 3 moves solution generate 16^3 +16^2+16 States.

Is the probleme my BFS?
The number of child created is the good one i made a lot of test.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: What's the purpose of the `find` variable? You never reassign it, the loop ends when you do `return visited`

Comment: Basically, if you visited a different number of nodes, or you visited the nodes in a different order, then it wouldn't be BFS. So rather you should be asking if there is anything better than BFS to solve your problem, but we can't answer that because you didn't actually describe what problem you are trying to use BFS to solve. See https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Okay, so to answer Barmar : the find variable should equals to true insted of returning visted list that was just for my test. To answer kaya3 : My bad i should have explained my problem, so im trying to solve Ricochet Robot (or Rasende Roboter) game , i made a lot of research on how to solve it and all the videos/code i saw were using BFS Algorithm. To be very clear , here in my BFS One state represent one robot movement, for exemple : Red Robot goes up is one state , blueRobot goes up is another state. I hope its better for you to understand now.